# I have SQL query that cast Date as Binary and then To Hex? How can i write same logic on c#?

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server

How to write

```
SUBSTRING(master.sys.fn_varbintohexstr(CAST(CreatedDate AS BINARY(9))),3,100))
```

this in c#?

Answer (score 0):

The closest I could get to this was:

```
//Get the date
System.DateTime a = System.DateTime.Now;

//Converts it to string
string b = a.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
System.Console.WriteLine(b);

//Convert to Byte Array
byte[] c = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(b);

//Convert every byte as hex and join it
string d = "";
foreach (byte e in c)
  d += string.Format("{0:x2}", e);

//Show the result
System.Console.WriteLine(d);
```

But id didn't worked the same way...

I hope this can help you to get to your code...

Comment: Thank you..Hex value should start from 0x right? Correct me if i am wrong.

Comment: For standard purposes, when you are coding, yes, it makes difference for number greater than 9, for example 10 vs 0x10. I chose not to use the "0x" because in his sample code, he removed it with the SUBSTRING method.

Comment: Thank you for clarification.

Comment: Final hex string from my database and C# is not same. But when i reverse my C# code, i am getting exact date. Does this result vary from framework/version?

Comment: I unsuccessful tried another way: long b = a.ToBinary(); and then System.BitConverter.GetBytes(b); but even this way the hex was not the same...

Comment: I also noticed when i do CAST(GetDate() AS decimal(38,14)) I get an OLE Automation Date. and converting in C# a.ToOADate() I got a different number (2.0f greater)